# Iframe shows authorized users

Tags: javascript, php, token

I created an "embed code" within my site, which is simply an iframe
I would give this code to embed only certain users but do not know how to do. a user could get inspecting the html code from the authorized sites and get the code without permission.
how do I make my site that only authorized users?
I thought about taking $ _SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER'] but as soon as you click a link to the internal frame the referrer is lost.

Comment: That really depends on how you want to do it. You could have a login. You could use a link that tests against a database. You could get a piece of Software that tests for the MAC address and have php `exec()` on it. This sounds like you're looking for an opinion. Where's your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really avoid authorized person inspecting the URL of the inline frame and revealing it to an unauthorized person. The right course of action is to serve an empty/error page to an unauthorized user.

You could achieve that by creating a session upon user login and verifying that session in the source code the of page displayed in the inline frame.

Do not rely on referrer, it is easily spoofable and some browsers won't even set it. Session cookie is not spoofable unless the user knows the credentials used to create it, which makes them authorized, whether or not they are authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the user with js.

```
<iframe src="verify.php">...
```

Verify.php contains:

```
<?php
session_start();
$id= generate sth random;
$_SESSION["id"]=$id;
?>
 <script>
window.location="http:yourdomain/site.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&referrer="+document.referrer;
 </script>
 Loading...
```

Now you can check the referrer, to verify if the site is correct and the id to check if nobody tried to trick you...

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION["id"]!=$_GET["id"] or $$_GET["referrer"]!="allowedsite.com"){
   echo "not valid";
   die();
}
?>
```

As Thomas Hübelbauer noted, people could still copy your code. The only thing you can do against it is obfuscation and the use of relative links. That makes it hard to copy.